# auto deactivate customer after 30min

Tags: customer

is it possible auto deactivate or change group of customers account after 30 min. of activation ?

Comment: you could always ask Vinai himself at https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation

Answer (score 2):

No, not out of the box.

And because you don't know at the moment, when the user was activated, there is no option to do it after 30min.

To solve this:

Save the time when a user was activated, write a cron job, which runs every few minutes to deactivate all users after 30min